# Validate user credentials against Azure AD without oAuth

Tags: go, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking to use Azure AD as my authentication system but do not want to bounce my users out to the Microsoft login page as it is disruptive and the fact that users may or may not have personal and or work accounts seems to make it quite confusing for most.

I have researched this quite a bit over the past few days but only find resources that show me AAD libraries in .NET, Azure Graph and Microsoft Graph API's. All of which seem to be convoluted systems that do the oAuth bounce through the Microsoft sign in window.

I am using Golang, but am an MSCA in .NET. If there are references to source code in .net that do not require proprietary / closed source DLL files I can use that as a starting point, or otherwise, if there is some reference point perhaps that shows how to use the MS Graph API to send username and password (entered on my site) and receive some positive or negative response indicating if the credentials provided match an account in my Azure AD would be great.

For example, I know of using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations to create, get, list, update and delete users. But it doesn't seem to have a validate or authorize procedure (unless of course I'm simply missing it).

My question is, is there a way to validate credentials without using oAuth through the Microsoft account sign in? If so can someone provide reference and or a bit of psuedo code to get me going in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically no.
No other OAuth/OpenIdConnect identity provider that I am aware of offers this either.
What if the account requires Multi-Factor Authentication?

There is Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow, but I would recommend not using it, since it does not work for accounts with MFA for instance.
That flow allows "non-interactive" authentication.
But if interaction is needed, it fails.

OAuth/OpenId Connect being "convoluted" is a matter of personal opinion.
Certain things are the way they are to make the process secure.
The redirect is necessary because the user is signing in to Office 365, not your app.
They should not give their passwords to you.

Seems people have been looking for a MS Graph library for Go: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/MSGraph-SDK-Code-Generator/issues/53.
No official one exists at the moment though :/

Comment: Thanks for the response, the resource owner grant flow is exactly what I'm looking for. I am looking to use AD as my own sites user / permission store, I'm not looking to allow users to authenticate outside of my tenant (and it's just a blog site, MFA isn't necessary).

Comment: Using the Resource Owner Password Credential flow is highly discouraged, and for your scenario it is simply not supported. Even if it's "just a blog site" you should not do this. Most blog platforms (e.g. WordPress) can be easily integrated for sign-in with Azure AD.

Comment: I don't recommend its use either. Main possible use case is "service accounts" when app-only access is not a good option/impossible

Comment: From what I read, it's discouraged because my site would be collecting username and password. Which I would understand if I was asking end users to sign in with their existing Microsoft accounts, but this is not the case. I am looking to use Azure AD programmatically as my user / permission store. Where in I will be creating these accounts from code when the user submits registration (I will know the password) then authenticating them against that same username & password. The alternative which I am likely doing is creating my own user account store. Why else would it be discouraged?

Comment: That might be a case where it is acceptable. Though in my own blog I still use OpenID Connect Authorization Code flow :)

Comment: Fair enough, I'm deciding against it at this point anyway but all good knowledge and insight. Thanks!